# Assign Multiple Data tables to single DevExpress Report, ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have three data-tables, having different columns. I want to show all three Datatables in a single DevExpress Report. I am new to DevExpress so Step-by-step explanation is highly appreciated.

I have tried the following code:

```
report.BeginInit();
        report.BeginUpdate();
        report.DataMember = "[Contract No]";  // Column [Contract No] is common in all three Datatables
        report.DataSource = initial; //"Initial" is Datatable1

        DetailReportBand initialReport = report.Bands["DetailReport"] as DetailReportBand;
        initialReport.DataSource = initial;
        DetailReportBand surv1 = report.Bands["DetailReport"] as   DetailReportBand;
        surv1.DataSource = dt; // "dt" is Datatable2
        DetailReportBand surv2Report = report.Bands["DetailReport"] as DetailReportBand;
        surv2Report.DataSource = surv2; //"surv2" is Datatable3

        report.FillDataSource();
        report.CreateDocument();
        ASPxDocumentViewer1.Report = report;
```

Here 'Report' is the instance of my external Class I used to create DevExpress Report.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its not 100% clear what _show all 3 Datatables_ means. What exactly is going wrong with your code? How is it working now and how do you want it to work?

Comment: @GER I want Three different grids on a single report with three different headings. I am getting only single (first data-table) in my report.